# Largest sum of upper-left quadrant of matrix that can be formed by reversing rows and columns

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm working on a HackerRank problem that's finding the largest sum of the elements in upper-left quadrant of a 2N x 2N matrix after reversing rows and columns. For example, if the matrix is

```
M = [
  112  42   83   119
  56   125  56   49
  15   78   101  43
  62   98   114  108
];
```

then the largest sum that can be formed from reversing rows and columns is `119 + 114 + 56 + 125 = 414` after getting the matrix

```
M' = [
   119  114  42   112
   56   125  101  49
   15   78   56   43
   62   98   83   108
];
```

from reversing column 2 and then row 0.

I have not figured out an easy solution, but I have come up with some facts that might be helpful:

- It is **not** possible to get any configuration from reversing rows and columns. Therefore, the answer cannot be to simply sort all the elements and sum the top `NxN` of them.
- Furthermore, it is not possible to move any 1 element to any other position. For example, the only possibly places for the element at (N-1,N-1) to be moved are (0,N-1),(N-1,0),(0,0).
- It requires 1 row reversal to get an element from the upper-right or bottom-left quadrant to the upper-left quadrant, and 2 reversals to get an element from the bottom-right quadrant to the upper-left quadrant.
- It's not possible to come up with a solution that simply looks at each element in the upper-left quadrant and checks whether it can be replaced by a larger element in the range of elements that can be moved in it's place (e.g. `M[0,1]=42` can be replaced by `M[0,2]=83` or `M[3,2]=114` or `M[3,1]=98`) because you have to also consider the other elements that get dragged along in the process.

Other than those facts, I cannot think of anything that helps me construct a simple solution. Is there any obvious fact that I am missing? I stayed up past midnight thinking about this last night. :)

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the original problem (to the constraints and stuff)?

Comment: @kraskevich I think I described it pretty well, but if you need ... https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-the-matrix

Comment: This sounds a lot like Sudoku.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's develop your observation about the fact that an element `(N - 1, N - 1)` can be only in `(0, 0)`, `(N - 1, 0)` or `(0, N - 1)` position.

- Consider an `(r, c)` element. One can observe that it can only be in one of the following four positions: `(r, c), (N - r - 1, c), (r, N - c - 1)` or `(N - 1 - r, N - 1 - c)`
- One can show that there is always a sequence of operations that places the largest of the four numbers located in the vertices of the rectangle described above to the upper-left quadrant without changing the rest of it (to prove it, one can just consider all cases and provide an explicit construction to do it. It's quite long but straightforward, so I'll not post it here).
- These two observation give the following solution:

  ```
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++)
          sum += max(a[i][j], a[i][n - j - 1], a[n - i - 1][j], a[n - i - 1][n - j - 1]);
  ```

Comment: best working solution.

Comment: very intutive explanation.

Comment: I am not clear how intuitive point 2 above is - I agree it seems the correct statement, but does anyone have a reference to proof?

Answer (score 14):

find the maximum upper-left-quadrant Sum value of the values of the cells,
for a square matrix.

The key point here is that every cell in a square matrix can be replaced
with only 3 other cells (by reversing a line, or a column - by transposing the matrix, reversing the line, and then transposing again),
hence to calculate (without changing the matrix) the max value of the upper-left-quadrant,
we only need to calculate the max value possible for every cell in the upper-left-quadrant.

1. In the (double) 'for' loop:

- scanning the upper-left-quadrant cells,
- fo each cell, comparing its value with the other 3 available-for-replacement values.
- using '//' to receive an int ('/' will give a float)

2. In the following 'Sum += ..' code:

- We can add the current cell [i, j] value (from the upper-left-quadrant) to the sum,
- or, add other cell value, for any cell that can be replaced with [i, j] within the matrix.
- Any cell in a square matrix can be replaced with only 3 other cells,
- hence, we choose the max value between the cell itself and the other 3.

```py
def maxSum(mat):
    R = C = len(mat)
    Sum = 0

    for i in range(0, R // 2):
        for j in range(0, C // 2):
            r1, r2 = i, R - i - 1
            c1, c2 = j, C - j - 1

            Sum += max(mat[r1][c1], mat[r1][c2],
                       mat[r2][c1], mat[r2][c2])

    return Sum


# Testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mat = [[112, 42, 83, 119],
           [56, 125, 56, 49],
           [15, 78, 101, 43],
           [62, 98, 114, 108]]

    print(maxSum(mat))  # 414
    exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

In cases, where no shortcuts come to mind, it is always possible to delegate. Not only to stackoverflow users, but also to the CPU. I.e. brute force search.
Brute force works for this small matrix - given a depth of 4 is already more than enough and given that the branching factor of the tree is `(2 * N)` where N is the number or rows and columns respectively. (N rows can be reversed and N columns.)

Here, for the 4x4 matrix in the question, a respective solution:

```ml
let data = 
    let values = 
        [|
            112;  42 ;  83;   119;
            56 ;  125;  56;   49;
            15 ;  78 ;  101;  43;
            62 ;  98 ;  114;  108
        |]
    Array2D.init 4 4 (fun r c -> values.[4 * r + c])

let upperQuadrantSum (m : int[,]) = 
    [ for r in 0..1 do for c in 0..1 do yield (r,c) ]
    |> List.sumBy (fun (r,c) -> m.[r,c])

let reverseRow row (m : int[,])  =
    Array2D.init 4 4 (fun r c -> if r = row then m.[r,3-c] else m.[r,c])
let reverseCol col (m : int[,]) =
    Array2D.init 4 4 (fun r c -> if c = col then m.[3-r,c] else m.[r,c])

let possibleActions = 
    [   reverseRow 0; reverseRow 1; reverseRow 2; reverseRow 3; 
        reverseCol 0; reverseCol 1; reverseCol 2; reverseCol 3; 
    ]

let maximize metric maxDepth m0 =
    let rec search depth m =
        let value = metric m
        if depth = maxDepth 
        then value
        else
            possibleActions 
            |> List.map (fun a -> let m1 = a m in max (metric m1) (search (depth+1) m1))
            |> List.max
            |> fun msearch -> max value msearch
    search 0 m0

let solve = maximize upperQuadrantSum
```

In fsi, issuing:

> solve 7 data;;
>   val it : int = 414

Of course, as stated in the other answer, once an optimization comes to mind,
it is nice to have the brute force solution in order to verify that both produce 
the same result:

```ml
let inline solve1 m = 
    let n = Array2D.length1 m
    let candidates r c =
        [ r,c ; n-1-r,c ; r,n-1-c ; n-1-r,n-1-c ]
    [
        for r in 0..n/2-1 do
            for c in 0..n/2-1 do
                yield (candidates r c |> List.map (fun (r,c) -> m.[r,c]) |> List.max)
    ] |> List.sum

solve1 data
```

Sorry for not writing the code in C#, but a .fsx file and fsi are so much easier than creating another C# application...

Answer (score 0):

LOL! I failed misserably this challenge many times by trying to come up with the algorithm to solve all the paths to the solution(kind of sneaky instructions). Here my way to solve it:

```
#Turn it into numpy for maximum pleasure
matrix=np.array(matrix)

#Measure its leangth
l=len(matrix)
ml=int(l/2)

#Move throught the four "corners" or "the-only-four-places-where-you-can-find-the-maximum-of-each-quadrant's-element"
max_vals = \
    [
        max(
            matrix[i,j],
            matrix[i,-(j+1)], 
            matrix[-(i+1),j],
            matrix[-(i+1),-(j+1)]
        )
        for j in range(ml)
        for i in range(ml)
    ]

#Return the sum of values
sum(max_vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix as:

```
112     42      83      119

56      125     56      49

15      78      101     43

62      98      114     108
```

Let be defined as:

```
A1      B1      B2      A2

C1      D1      D2      C2

C3      D3      D4      C4

A3      B3      B4      A4
```

Now we have to calculate sum of the highest value of the matrices,

```
A1, A2, A3, A4,
B1, B2, B3, B4,
C1, C2, C3, C4,
D1, D2, D3, D4
```

Which can be achieved by:

```
public static void CaculateSum(List<List<int>> matrix)
{
    int length = matrix.Count;
    int halfLength = length / 2;
    length--;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < halfLength; j++)
        {
            int a1 = matrix[i][j];
            int a2 = matrix[i][length - j];
            int a3 = matrix[length - i][j];
            int a4 = matrix[length - i][length - j];

            int[] elements = { a1, a2, a3, a4 };
            sum += elements.Max();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);   
   
}
```