# Flip rows and columns of an array until the sum of the elements in the upper left quadrant is maximal

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, optimization

There is a HackerRank coding challenge on which asks the programmer to find the largest sum of the elements in the upper left quadrant of a matrix by reversing either rows or columns.

[Here's a link to a similar post with working answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205519/largest-sum-of-upper-left-quadrant-of-matrix-that-can-be-formed-by-reversing-row)

I'm trying to actually return the new matrix rather than just the sum. I've come up with something, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it. I could really use some pointers on how to make this better. My algorithm goes something like this

1. Calculate the sum of the upper left quadrant
2. Clone data of input matrix into a variable "maxMatrix"
3. Flip a row
4. Check if the current sum > previous sum
5. If true, make appropriate changes to maxMatrix
6. Flip column
7. Repeat steps 4-5
8. Repeat until sum is maximal

The code I came up with looks like this

```
public static int upperLeftSum(int[][] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        
        // Find sum of upper left quadrant
        for(int l =0;l<arr.length/2;l++) {
            for(int c= 0;c<arr.length/2;c++) {
                //System.out.print(arr[l][c] + " ");
                sum += arr[l][c];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    
    }
    
    public static int[][] reverseRow(int[][] arr, int row){

        // We calculate the sum of the elements at each half of the row
        int firsthalf = 0, secondhalf = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length/2;i++) {
            firsthalf += arr[row][i];
            secondhalf += arr[row][arr.length - i -1];
        }
        
        // If the sum of the right half of the row is bigger, we flip the row
        if(firsthalf < secondhalf){
            int start = 0, end = arr.length -1;

            while(start < end) {
                int temp = arr[row][start];
                arr[row][start] = arr[row][end];
                arr[row][end] = temp;
            
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
        
        
        return arr;
    }
    
    public static int[][] reverseColumn(int[][] arr, int col){

        // We calculate the sum of the elements at each half of the column
        int firsthalf = 0, secondhalf = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length/2;i++) {
            firsthalf += arr[i][col];
            secondhalf += arr[arr.length - i - 1][col];
        }

        // If the sum of the right half of the row is bigger, we flip the column
        if(firsthalf < secondhalf){
            int start = 0, end = arr.length -1;

            while(start < end) {
                int temp = arr[start][col];
                arr[start][col] = arr[end][col];
                arr[end][col] = temp;
            
                start++;
                end--;
            }    
        }
        

        return arr;
    }
    
    public static int[][] matrixGame(int[][] arr){
        int maxSum = upperLeftSum(arr);
        int[][] maxMatrix = new int[arr.length][arr.length];
        
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            maxMatrix[i] = arr[i].clone();
        }
        
        boolean maximal = false;
        int l = 0;
        while(l<arr.length*2) {
            int firsthalf = 0, secondhalf = 0;

            
            if(l % 2 == 0){
                arr = reverseRow(arr, l/2);
            }
            else{
                arr = reverseColumn(arr, l/2);
            }
            
            int sum = upperLeftSum(arr);
            if(sum > maxSum) {
                //System.out.println(sum + " is greater than " + maxSum + ". Therefore, the currently maximized array is");
                maxSum = sum;
                //maxMatrix = arr.clone();
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                    maxMatrix[i] = arr[i].clone();
                }
                //printMatrix(maxMatrix);
                l=0;
            } else {
                l++;
            }
        }
        
        return maxMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: If all you want is to improve your working code, it's better to post on the Code Review Stack Exchange

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Jorn I understand. I did not know Code Review Stack exchange existed. Thank you for showing me that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matrix has N rows and M columns
Observations:

1. Elements at Position `(x,y) <-> (N-x,y) <-> (x, M-y) <-> (N-x, M-y)` can be exchanged among themselves but not with any other position.
2. If the maximum element among these is fixed at the top left position, i.e. `(x,y)` then the other three can occupy the remaining positions in 3P3 = 6 `(nPr = n!/(n-r)!)` ways.

To find any maximum matrix, you can fix the maximum element for each value of (x,y) at the top left and arrange the remaining in any way you want.

To find all the maximum matrices you'll have to generate all possible combinations `(6^(N/2 * M/2))`